# Views exposed filter autocomplete weird function() code

Tags: views, forms, security

Should one worry when a Views exposed filter autocompletes a function for certain words?

1. Type `fbn` on the exposed filter field for Users. This is an autocomplete field.
   RESULT: The autocomplete list offers two options starting with `function(..)`. See image.[image: Weird Drupal Views autocomplete options]
2. Choose the first option, `function (E, F) ...`
   RESULT: The word `filter` is filled in.
3. Type again `fbn` in the field, then choose the secons option, `function (B, C) ...`
   RESULT: The word `indexOf` is entered.

Inspecting the elements doesn't work very well, as soon as the focus leaves the field the autocomplete vanishes. I'll try some more with a network sniffer or Firefox instead of WebKit, maybe I'll have more luck.

This could be an XSS injection attempt. Should I worry?

Comment: You should use the Network tab of Firebug to inspect the json response from server; if the "spurious" entries are there, you should check the ahah/ajax callback that is returning them.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is a major problem.  I had a similar problem a while back ( I don't remember how I cleaned it up :( ).  I would recommend you do check on another browser, but also try running update in the URL  (example.com/update.php) this script makes certain that all DB updates of  modules are completed.  If it persists, you may want to visit the Views issues site at Drupal.org.

Please post back on this page with what worked.